# How to get value of item in JSON array c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, json-deserialization

So, please read this detail for more information. I get error at 
`Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'.` when i try get value of items of array.

The array is:

```
{
    [
        {
            "GROUP_MOD_ID": "G06",
            "ADMIN": 1,
            "USERS": 0
        }
     ]
}
```

This is snippet code

```
  dynamic obj_str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);
                string value_admin = obj_str["ADMIN"];
                Console.WriteLine(value_admin);       
                if (value_admin == "1")
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
```

. Thank all.
[image: example picture]

Comment: The JSON string you posted has curly-braced surrounding the array. This is not valid JSON syntax. What is the raw value of the input string (or stream) you're using?

Comment: Dear @Dai, `obj` is type of string `[{"GROUP_MOD_ID":"G06","ADMIN":1,"USERS":0}]`

Comment: @BrianCrist please see my answer

Comment: @viveknuna , so good, it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `dynamic` in this case. I generally recommend avoiding `dynamic` in C#. Instead I prefer the `JToken`-style approach (in the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace, though it doesn't mean you have to use Linq):

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse( input );
JObject firstObject = (JObject)array.First;
String adminValue = (String)firstObject.GetValue("ADMIN");
```

In production you'll want to add input validation code to ensure the input JSON array and object actually has elements and values and handle those errors accordingly.

But if you're certain that the input is correct you can reduce this down to a single-line:

```
String adminValue = (String)( ((JObject)JArray.Parse( input )).First.GetValue("ADMIN") );
```

...at the cost of readbility, of course.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your JSON seems to be incorrect.

Correct JSON:

```
[{
"GROUP_MOD_ID": "G06",
"ADMIN": 1,
"USERS": 0
}]
```

And when you desialize this json, it will give you array of array.

You code will be:

```
    dynamic obj_str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    string value_admin = obj_str[0].ADMIN;
    Console.WriteLine(value_admin);
    if (value_admin == "1")
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

You can see this by doing this way to.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string GROUP_MOD_ID { get; set; }
    public int ADMIN { get; set; }
    public int USERS { get; set; }
}
```

Code to deserialize:

```
    SampleClass[] obj_str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass[]>(json);
    int value_admin = obj_str[0].ADMIN;
    Console.WriteLine(value_admin);
    if (value_admin == 1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have, according to above, it's work but i have create a new class.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work only if you have json as

var obj="{'GROUP_MOD_ID':'G06','ADMIN':10,'USERS':0}";

or

```
    var obj="[{'GROUP_MOD_ID':'G06','ADMIN':1,'USERS':0}]";

    dynamic obj_str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);
            string value_admin = obj_str[0]["ADMIN"];
            Console.WriteLine(value_admin);
```

Comment: Dear @Dharminder Singh, after , i had use this , but it gets same error `Method not found: 'System.String System.String.Format(System.IFormatProvider, System.String, System.Object)'.`

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of you make model for Deserialize Object.

Your model like this.

```
public class Test_Model
{
    [JsonProperty("GROUP_MOD_ID")]
    public string GROUP_MOD_ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ADMIN")]
    public int ADMIN { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("USERS")]
    public int USERS { get; set; }
}
```

and after write this code:

```
        var obj_str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test_Model>(obj);
        int value_admin = obj_str.ADMIN;
        Console.WriteLine(value_admin);
        if (value_admin == 1)
            return true;
        else return false;
```

I hope so your problem sort out.